# Fragment replace flashing old fragment

Tags: android-fragments

I am replacing fragments into framelayout.But when I am replacing,old fragment is showing for a second then it is replacing.How can I prevent from flashing old fragment ? I am using this code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
SettingsFragment conv=new SettingsFragment();
SettingsFragment.newInstance(LOGGED_USERNAME);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,conv);
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Any update on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. I've found a workaround - first add new fragment, then show it and hide old. And then remove old in the async task. The solution is a bit confusing, but I didn't find anything better.
In the following example old fragment has tag `fragment` and the new one `fragment2`.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "fragment2").commit();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragment).commit();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment")).commit();
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment")).commit();                      
                    }
                }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 5):

My phone has recently upgraded to Marshmallow (Galaxy S6), and since then all of my fragments 'flash' instead of a fast fade-in / subtle scale-up that the fragment transition used to provide. Removing the transaction's transition entirely:

`fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);`

Seems to have fixed the issue. I would suggest trying to implement a custom animation on the transaction to see if that helps.

Comment: This does work, but it causes the app to be unstable and crash when switching the tabs very rapidly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  In my case it was caused by:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

Just removed `android:animateLayoutChanges` from the flickering fragment and smooth transitions returned.